# Client credentials for a API Gateway using OAuth2

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, microservices, api-gateway

I'm trying to understand Microservice architecture using OAuth2.0. I've understood about how OAuth2.0 works. I saw one of the grant type is Client credentials, which it requires client id and client secret key and with that help it will generate a access token.

This may be a stupid question, but still I'm not able to understand how to integrate it into my application.

I've 10 clients who are trying to call my API gateway.

Do the customers should have different client credentials? Do they need to call the Authorization server to generate the access token? or do they send the client credentials to the API gateway to generate the access token and proceed further?

Where should be the client credentials stored?

Please help me in understanding.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of clients are they?

- Web / Mobile UIs?
- Back end API clients from business partners?

In either case:

- The client will get tokens from the Authorization Server
- The API / Gateway will only receive tokens - never credentials

For back end API clients you would configure a client id and secret for each of them in the Authorization Server, then send it to each customer as part of onboarding them.

Comment: They are Web UIs. So, how does my application will authorize the token? How do I know that the request is authorized

Comment: For an instance, if I have 1000 customers, all of them needs to be registered under Authorization server?

Comment: If there is a single app used by 1000 end users, you would register a single OAuth Client. The app would use Authorization Code Flow to get a token from the Auth Server. The token would be sent to the API which would need to validate it. Maybe have a read of my [OAuth Messages](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/) blog post to see how this fits together

Comment: Thanks Gary. I will take a look.